# State Design Pattern with Interfaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, interface, garbage-collection

I'm reading a book with [Design Patterns for Unity](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/hands-game-development-patterns-unity-2019) and I learned about "State Pattern". The curios thing for me is that it the first time when I saw this pattern used with Interfaces. He makes all states using interfaces.

```
public class Ship : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IShipState m_CurrentState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        IShipState m_CurrentState = new NormalShipState();
        m_CurrentState.Execute(this);
    }

    public void Normalize()
    {
        m_CurrentState = new NormalShipState();
        m_CurrentState.Execute(this);
    }

    public void TriggerRedAlert()
    {
        m_CurrentState = new AlertShipState();
        m_CurrentState.Execute(this);
    }

    public void DisableShip()
    {
        m_CurrentState = new DisabledShipState();
        m_CurrentState.Execute(this);        
    }

    public void LogStatus(string status)
    {
        Debug.Log(status);
    }
}
```

I don't understand exactly what happens when the variable m_CurrentState is "re-initialized". So we in Awake we make our m_CurrentState as a NormalShipState. But when we request a change of state this variable "m_CurrenState" what happens exactly?
I have read about Garbage Collection and all of his stages and that he will released the dead objects making place for other objects. But what happens with this "m_CurrentState" when we make new() call?

1. What happens with the old memory? It will be collected by Garbage Collector?
2. It makes a new memory allocation everytime I request a change of state and can cause memory overflow?

Comment: Garbage collection has nothing to do with the algorithm or the pattern. Objects are eventually garbage collected, if nothing has a reference to them, or else not if the memory isn't needed. The amount of memory being allocated is probably microscopic compared to everything else going on in the program, and if you don't have lingering references there's no cause for concern in any case. Everything in .NET uses operator new again and again and again and again. Creating class instances is not a dangerous practice.

Comment: Thanks man, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no other references to the object previously referenced by `m_CurrentState`, then that object will be garbage collected, if there are, then it won't.

It's the same as any other object, it doesn't have special garbage collection rules simply because it's an interface.